# ASP.Net FileUpload control causes google chrome to crash and show broken data

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, file-upload, webkit, crash

I am working on an asp.net page that contains a fileupload server control (not async fileupload).

I recently noticed that whenever that control is on the page and any postback occurs, the page crashes and stops executing..giving me strange and broken data like in the screenshot attached!!

I also noticed that is happening in any webkit based browser (e.g safari, chrome, etc..)

Strangely, the problem is only occurring when am running this page online, but when am debugging it locally, this problem doesn't occur!!

Any ideas??

**Note**: The following link [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpe24.png ] is a screen of how the crash looks like, and i remember something now, i used to get this screen sometimes while am browsing through google.com or images.google.com !! hope this helps :S

Comment: Would you please post some code? Really hard to help without having a clue. And there is no screenshot attached...

Comment: There is no screenshot probably because you are a new user and don't have permissions to add it. Please provide a link in some other way.

Also does the browser crash after the file is sent to the server or before that?

Comment: yea, i cant actually attach right now...but, @Stilgar the crash happens even if i dont upload anything...that means if am just having the control on the page and postback using any other control...the page breaks down with rubbish data everywhere...:S

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this whole problem was caused by the compression module referenced in the web.config file.

As a permanent solution however, I changed all **FileUpload** controls to **AsyncFileUpload**, gaining both a solution and an easier way to navigate and work.

Thanks everyone ;)